# how to distungish a integer variable while reading a file in c program

Tags: c, file-handling

I tried a simple c program to read data from a file that contains names and marks of students and i wanted to calculate the total marks of the students. When executing my code the output displays as total = 0.
Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen("detail.txt","r");
    int marks, total = 0;
    while(fscanf(file1,"%d",&marks)!= EOF){
        total = total + marks;
    }
    printf("Total = %d\n",total);
    fclose(file1);
}
```

Here is my file that contains the data:

```
john 25
Malik 78
smith 85
irik 85
hales 98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the string as well. Otherwise you will attempt to read the string `john` as a decimal integer in the very first call to `fscanf`, and it will [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) *zero* (not `EOF`).

And since the `fscanf` call failed to parse the first string with the `%d` format, the input file pointer doesn't advance, so the next call to `fscanf` will attempt to read and parse the string `john` *again* and fail. And so on and on and on... Forever.

You can discard the string if you don't need it, which can be done in the `fscanf` format string itself:

```
fscanf(file1, "%*s %d", &marks)
```

As documented in e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) the asterisk `*` is an assignment suppression operator, which reads and parses the format, but doesn't assign to a variable.

And if the `fscanf` call was successful it will return `1`, which is better to check against in your loop condition.